# C# -- Should I NULL an object if it has no use in the following scope?

Tags: c#

Given the following question, I am asking the "C# Best Practice".

```
    File.WriteAllText("YourXaml.xaml", txtXamlData.Text);

    Window myWindow = null;
    try
    {
        using (Stream sr = File.Open("YourXaml.xaml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            myWindow = (Window)XamlReader.Load(sr);
            myWindow.ShowDialog();
            myWindow.Close();
            myWindow = null; // **should we do this?**
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {       
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: [Should I assign null to my local variables?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/26/should-i-assign-null-to-my-local-variables.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, don't do it. It's just clutter, and it's not going to help in any way, shape or form<sup>1</sup>. The garbage collector is smart enough to tell when the variable is last read within the program code, and will allow it to be garbage collected regardless. I assume that you *don't* refer to `myWindow` elsewhere in the code?

Personally I'd rewrite that code to declare `myWindow` later though:

```
File.WriteAllText("YourXaml.xaml", txtXamlData.Text);

try
{
    using (Stream sr = File.Open("YourXaml.xaml", FileMode.Open))
    {
        Window myWindow = (Window)XamlReader.Load(sr);
        myWindow.ShowDialog();            
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ... 
}
```

Note that I originally had a `using` statement here to dispose of `myWindow`... but it seems `Window` doesn't implement `IDisposable`. I doubt that you need to call `Close()` after `ShowDialog()` has returned though - surely it blocks until the window *has* been closed.

---

<sup>1</sup> Okay, it will allow earlier garbage collection *if* you're debugging and you're stepping through, and have reached a point after that line. In release mode it's pointless though.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't use `myWindow` in later parts of the code, you could move its declaration closer to its usage:

```
File.WriteAllText("YourXaml.xaml", txtXamlData.Text);

try
{
    using (Stream sr = File.Open("YourXaml.xaml", FileMode.Open))
    {
        Window myWindow = (Window)XamlReader.Load(sr);
        myWindow.ShowDialog();
        myWindow.Close();
    }
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{       
}
```

Comment: Why? This won't this basically do the same?

Comment: @Alxandr AFAIK, declarations reserve space, so no.

Comment: @Alxandr It makes the code easier to read. "Declaring everything at the top of the function" is an outdated practice that originated from C's (original) limitations. "Declare near first use" is recommended here.

Comment: It's nearly the same, but a little more cleaned up.

Comment: Yeah, I get the easier to read part, but optimized compiled code it will be the same, no?

Comment: @Alxandr: If the compiler sees that this object won't be used later, it could do exactly the same what I did and move the declaration to the inner scope. The garbage collector then could clean it up earlier at runtime.

Comment: @Norbert, It doesn't answer my question though.

Comment: @Joe: If the jitter decides to put the local on the temporary store then their stack location is created when the method is entered, not when the block is entered. If the local is hoisted to the heap then you are correct; the space for the declaration is not reserved until control enters the block. However, this is really a bit of a hairsplitting distinction. It really doesn't matter when the "top of the GC" pointer is moved or when the "top of the stack" pointer is moved. It's just a pointer move either way.

Comment: @Eric I obviously need to do my research on how the jitter works because it seems to "complicate" the answer to every question involving delcaration/allocation :)

Comment: @Joe: Or of course the jitter could choose to enregister the local, in which case it really doesn't make much sense at all to say that its storage has been "created". That register was created in a clean room at Intel and it's going to be there for some time. Basically the issue is that the compiler and the runtime have broad lattitude to decide how, when, and where to create and reclaim storage for variables, and most of the time it doesn't make a bit of difference to the C# programmer. Let the memory manager manage memory, and worry about something else.

Answer (score 2):

No.  The garbage collector will still need to clean up the object, and the only possible benefit of doing that would be that code later on in the function attempting to use it would get a null reference exception, which could indicate that you no longer intent for the variable to be used.  In practice, it's almost always an antipattern.

Comment: The code was borrowed from "Prof C# 2010 and .NET 4 Platform" which is a good C# book. However, it does include some outdated code. -thx

Answer (score 1):

Depends. `myWindow` is still in scope following the `try...catch` block. Even though it's been closed, is `myWindow` going to be referenced further on in the method? Setting it to `null` will make explicit your intent that it not be referenced later (as the NullReferenceException should get their attention.

It would seem though that the better approach would be to move the declaration of myWindow into the try clause and not worry about it.

```
try
{
    using (Stream sr = File.Open("YourXaml.xaml", FileMode.Open))
    {
      Window myWindow = (Window)XamlReader.Load(sr);
      myWindow.ShowDialog();
      myWindow.Close();
    }
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just declare the `myWindow` variable inside the `using` block to begin with? Then it would be out of scope once it leaves that block and would be a candidate for garbage collection.

Comment: nitpicking: the JIT optimizer will actually detect its last use in the method and make it eligible for GC immediately after the last usage, even within the declaring method.

Comment: Even without setting the variable to null or declaring the variable inside the using block (which I would recommend anyway), the object is elegible for garbage collection. The GC is allowed to consider variables dead—even when they are in scope—if no future path of execution will use the variable. It is my understanding that some versions of the runtime actually do this in practice.

Comment: @Jeffrey: You are correct, and this becomes observable in situations like "{ Frob f = new Frob(); NativeCode.DoSomething(f); }".  Here the jitter "knows" that f is "dead" immediately *after* it transfers control to DoSomething; just because local f is still "on the stack" and just because a call to native code is in flight does not keep the referent of f alive. The referent can be reclaimed on the GC thread while the main thread is running DoSomething, which can cause all manner of horrid bugs. You have to use the KeepAlive method to keep it alive during the native call.